# python dictionary with constant value-type

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, dictionary

I bumped into a case where I need a big (=huge) python dictionary, which turned to be quite memory-consuming.
However, since all of the values are of a single type (long) - as well as the keys,  I figured I can use python (or numpy, doesn't really matter) array for the values ; and wrap the needed interface (in: x ; out: d[x]) with an object which actually uses these arrays for the keys and values storage.

I can use a index-conversion object (input --> index, of 1..n, where n is the different-values counter), and return array[index]. I can elaborate on some techniques of how to implement such an indexing-methods with reasonable memory requirement, it works and even pretty good. 
However, I wonder if there is such a data-structure-object already exists (in python, or wrapped to python from C/++), in any package (I checked collections, and some Google searches).

Any comment will be welcome, thanks.

Comment: You should consider using Tuples as opposed to Lists if you haven't done so already; Python does not have plain "arrays", but Tuples are definitely more memory-efficient, as it does not reserve space for insertions. A dictionary, however, still chews up memory because of the hash table, so you may want to consider using a sorted data structure and use binary search to find the keys you want, which maps to the index of the Tuple.

Comment: Why are you thinking about plain-Python realization? May be it worth to look for any out-of-box key-value storage solution with indexing already implemented, like Tokyo Cabinet for example?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of task is a typical database-type access (large volume of data in columns of a given type).  You would create a simple table with indexed keys, for fast access.  I don't have experience with it, but you might want to check out the standard [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) module.

If your keys do not change over time, you could alternatively put all your data in two Python memory-optimized arrays (standard `array` module); one array contains the sorted keys, and the other one the corresponding values.  You could then find key indexes through the optimized `bisect.bisect` function.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using std::map. Boost.Python provides a Python wrapping for std::map out-of-the-box.